# How to get REMOTE_USER working with Django in Pycharm and Firefox for Windows Authentication?

Tags: django, windows, authentication, firefox, ldap

I'm setting up a django app which uses windows authentication (LDAP) to populate users in the database. It works but doesn't sign in automatically. I've followed a bunch of guides but no luck. Can't see REMOTE_USER in the request on my django server, debugging in Pycharm.

Already tried:
https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Configuring-Firefox-for-Integrated-Windows-Authentication
- under network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris I set it to:
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/, ldap://xx.example.com'
Was unsure if it's supposed to be web app server (local) or the ldap server. Ended up setting all the URI fields in about:config to this to try cover all cases.

In django I followed this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/auth-remote-user/
- Set MIDDLEWARE and AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'home.authentication.earlston_ad',
```

I'd expect request.META['REMOTE_USER'] to exist and have users LDAP info. But this field doesn't exist.

---

**Update**

Got a little further. I hadn't configured the IIS server running the django project for Windows Authentication properly. This [link](https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Networking/Single_Sign_On/SSO_with_IIS_on_Windows.html) helped.
Have concluded that perhaps the standard django debugging server in Pycharm doesn't support LDAP/Remote User together.

So I have IE and chrome working with automatic SSI. However Firefox is still asking for login. I ran this in CMD of the server:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN%
```

which returned AMBER.DDE.CO.UK

I then went to about:config in Firefox settings and added "AMBER.DDE.CO.UK" to:

```
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
```

Still asking for login details. Am I putting the right thing in the trusted uri?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually receiving and passing the header to Django? It could be consumed by something earlier in your stack or not arriving at all.

Comment: Not at all. I'm not even sure if I've got firefox setup correctly. Do you know of any ways to test earlier in the stack if it's getting the AD credentials?

Comment: You can use the developer tools in the browser to see what your browser is sending to the server.  If you're just running the Django development server, you can up the verbosity of the `runserver` command with `--verbosity 3`.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I'm close but still struggling with firefox. Any ideas on the update?